# Day, month and year clone in to one with MomentJS

Tags: javascript, datetime, angular.js

There are two methods I am using here for merging day, month and year.

**First one**

```
$scope.firstOption = moment(new Date($scope.register.db.day + ' ' + $scope.register.db.month + ' ' + $scope.register.db.year));
```

**Second One**

```
$scope.secondOption = moment($scope.register.db.day + $scope.register.db.month + $scope.register.db.year).format('MMMM Do YYYY');
```

Unfortunately, there is a warning in the console which says:

> Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This
>   is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please
>   refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.
>   Arguments: [object Object]

Is there any best practice to clone those three fields?

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPJrzx)

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['angularMoment']).controller('registerCtrl', function($scope, moment) {
  console.log(moment('12-12-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY').isValid());
  $scope.registerMe = function(argument) {
    $scope.firstOption = moment(new Date($scope.register.db.day + ' ' + $scope.register.db.month + ' ' + $scope.register.db.year));
    console.log($scope.kooy);
    $scope.secondOption = moment($scope.register.db.day + $scope.register.db.month + $scope.register.db.year).format('MMMM Do YYYY');
    console.log($scope.keey);

  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-moment/0.10.3/angular-moment.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="registerCtrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 bg-primary">
      <h4 class="text-center">Register your appointment</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="registerMe()">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-3 control-label">Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" ng-model="register.name">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-3 control-label">Date of birth</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="register.db.day">
                  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Day</option>
                  <option value="01">01</option>
                  <option value="02">02</option>
                  <option value="03">03</option>
                  <option value="04">04</option>
                  <option value="05">05</option>
                  <option value="06">06</option>
                  <option value="07">07</option>
                  <option value="08">08</option>
                  <option value="09">09</option>
                  <option value="10">10</option>
                  <option value="11">11</option>
                  <option value="12">12</option>
                  <option value="13">13</option>
                  <option value="14">14</option>
                  <option value="15">15</option>
                  <option value="16">16</option>
                  <option value="17">17</option>
                  <option value="18">18</option>
                  <option value="19">19</option>
                  <option value="20">20</option>
                  <option value="21">21</option>
                  <option value="22">22</option>
                  <option value="23">23</option>
                  <option value="24">24</option>
                  <option value="25">25</option>
                  <option value="26">26</option>
                  <option value="27">27</option>
                  <option value="28">28</option>
                  <option value="29">29</option>
                  <option value="30">30</option>
                  <option value="31">31</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-5">
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="register.db.month">
                  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Month</option>
                  <option value="january">January</option>
                  <option value="february">February</option>
                  <option value="march">March</option>
                  <option value="april">April</option>
                  <option value="may">May</option>
                  <option value="june">June</option>
                  <option value="july">July</option>
                  <option value="august">August</option>
                  <option value="september">September</option>
                  <option value="october">October</option>
                  <option value="november">November</option>
                  <option value="december">December</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-4">
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="register.db.year">
                  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Year</option>
                  <option value="1901">1901</option>
                  <option value="1902">1902</option>
                  <option value="1903">1903</option>
                  <option value="1904">1904</option>
                  <option value="1905">1905</option>
                  <option value="1906">1906</option>
                  <option value="1907">1907</option>
                  <option value="1908">1908</option>
                  <option value="1909">1909</option>
                  <option value="1910">1910</option>
                  <option value="1911">1911</option>
                  <option value="1912">1912</option>
                  <option value="1913">1913</option>
                  <option value="1914">1914</option>
                  <option value="1915">1915</option>
                  <option value="1916">1916</option>
                  <option value="1917">1917</option>
                  <option value="1918">1918</option>
                  <option value="1919">1919</option>
                  <option value="1920">1920</option>
                  <option value="1921">1921</option>
                  <option value="1922">1922</option>
                  <option value="1923">1923</option>
                  <option value="1924">1924</option>
                  <option value="1925">1925</option>
                  <option value="1926">1926</option>
                  <option value="1927">1927</option>
                  <option value="1928">1928</option>
                  <option value="1929">1929</option>
                  <option value="1930">1930</option>
                  <option value="1931">1931</option>
                  <option value="1932">1932</option>
                  <option value="1933">1933</option>
                  <option value="1934">1934</option>
                  <option value="1935">1935</option>
                  <option value="1936">1936</option>
                  <option value="1937">1937</option>
                  <option value="1938">1938</option>
                  <option value="1939">1939</option>
                  <option value="1940">1940</option>
                  <option value="1941">1941</option>
                  <option value="1942">1942</option>
                  <option value="1943">1943</option>
                  <option value="1944">1944</option>
                  <option value="1945">1945</option>
                  <option value="1946">1946</option>
                  <option value="1947">1947</option>
                  <option value="1948">1948</option>
                  <option value="1949">1949</option>
                  <option value="1950">1950</option>
                  <option value="1951">1951</option>
                  <option value="1952">1952</option>
                  <option value="1953">1953</option>
                  <option value="1954">1954</option>
                  <option value="1955">1955</option>
                  <option value="1956">1956</option>
                  <option value="1957">1957</option>
                  <option value="1958">1958</option>
                  <option value="1959">1959</option>
                  <option value="1960">1960</option>
                  <option value="1961">1961</option>
                  <option value="1962">1962</option>
                  <option value="1963">1963</option>
                  <option value="1964">1964</option>
                  <option value="1965">1965</option>
                  <option value="1966">1966</option>
                  <option value="1967">1967</option>
                  <option value="1968">1968</option>
                  <option value="1969">1969</option>
                  <option value="1970">1970</option>
                  <option value="1971">1971</option>
                  <option value="1972">1972</option>
                  <option value="1973">1973</option>
                  <option value="1974">1974</option>
                  <option value="1975">1975</option>
                  <option value="1976">1976</option>
                  <option value="1977">1977</option>
                  <option value="1978">1978</option>
                  <option value="1979">1979</option>
                  <option value="1980">1980</option>
                  <option value="1981">1981</option>
                  <option value="1982">1982</option>
                  <option value="1983">1983</option>
                  <option value="1984">1984</option>
                  <option value="1985">1985</option>
                  <option value="1986">1986</option>
                  <option value="1987">1987</option>
                  <option value="1988">1988</option>
                  <option value="1989">1989</option>
                  <option value="1990">1990</option>
                  <option value="1991">1991</option>
                  <option value="1992">1992</option>
                  <option value="1993">1993</option>
                  <option value="1994">1994</option>
                  <option value="1995">1995</option>
                  <option value="1996">1996</option>
                  <option value="1997">1997</option>
                  <option value="1998">1998</option>
                  <option value="1999">1999</option>
                  <option value="2001">2001</option>
                  <option value="2002">2002</option>
                  <option value="2003">2003</option>
                  <option value="2004">2004</option>
                  <option value="2005">2005</option>
                  <option value="2006">2006</option>
                  <option value="2007">2007</option>
                  <option value="2008">2008</option>
                  <option value="2009">2009</option>
                  <option value="2010">2010</option>
                  <option value="2011">2011</option>
                  <option value="2012">2012</option>
                  <option value="2013">2013</option>
                  <option value="2014">2014</option>
                  <option value="2015">2015</option>
                  <option value="2016">2016</option>
                  <option value="2017">2017</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-3 control-label">Mobile</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile" ng-model="register.mobile">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-3 control-label">Email</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-6">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" ng-model="register.email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-3 control-label">City</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City" ng-model="register.city">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-md-6">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm12">
      <!-- <span am-time-ago=" register.db.year | amFromUnix"></span> -->
      <!-- <p am-time-ago="1980">{{ '1986' | amStartOf:'year' }}</p> -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"><pre>{{ register | json}}</pre>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"><pre>{{firstOption | json}}</pre>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"><pre>{{secondOption | json}}</pre>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand why somebody doing down vote  there is nothing wrong on the code I just need to review my code for best practice

Comment: I didn't downvote but why don't you read the comments on the issue and follow the advice there?

Comment: @RobH I said somebody, not you mate.

Comment: Apart from the linked docs the repetition of years and days of a month is standing out. You're already using JavaScript, so you might as well generate that at runtime instead of writing out HTML.

Answer (score 2):

All that fuss only meant: Moment will soon only parse ISO date strings. To parse arbitrary date strings reliably, you will need to *describe the format via the second argument of the `moment` function*. That's it.

```
$scope.date = moment($scope.register.db.day + $scope.register.db.month + $scope.register.db.year, 'DD MMMM YYYY');
```

Also, consider breaking out that string into variables and consider using template strings to assemble the date string:

```
let day = $scope.register.db.day;
let month = $scope.register.db.month;
let year = $scope.register.db.year;

$scope.date = moment(`${day} ${month} ${year}`, 'DD MM YYYY');
```

Aside from that, consider creating the dates, months and years selection in JS and just loop through it in the template.